# log4net with asp.net core 2

Tags: log4net, asp.net-core-2.0

i'm using log4net to create log files dynamicaly , i tried the following steps here http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/dynamic-log-filenames-with-log4net.aspx but i'm getting (null).txt file ,   Here is my log4net.config file

```
 `<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="app_data/log/%date{yyyy-MM-dd}/%property{LogName}.txt" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value=" %-5level %date{dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %logger [%thread] - %message %exception%newline%property{LogName}" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <level value="All" />
  </root>
</log4net>`
```

and this is my test code

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "xx@xx.xx";
```

As i said i'm getting (null).txt FileName instead of xx@xx.xx.txt , thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code and its working just fine, so I can only assume, that you are assigning your GlobalContext property to late. Remember, to set it before you call `XmlConfigurator.Configure` method. Set it up in your Program.cs file like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ...

        GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "xx@xx.xx";
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

        // ...
    }
}
```